# Sort the collection by frequency of the Stream API

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

Hello everyone working with streams, there was such a question. I have a sheet that I want to sort by the frequency of occurrence of characters in it:

```
List<String> frequency = new ArrayList<>();
        Collections.addAll(frequency, "gg", "ss", "gg", "boy", "girls", "girls", "gg", "boy", "aa", "aa");
```

I wrote this method:

```
return words.stream().limit(limit).map(String::toLowerCase)
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),Collectors.counting()))
                    .entrySet().stream()
                    .map(entry -> new Pair<>(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But the answer is already displayed is not correct, the string a is completely lost, the string gg is one element, and the boys is one element

```
ss=1
gg=2
girls=2
boy=1
```

And I don’t know how to sort them by frequency of occurrence.
The result should be like this:

```
gg=3
aa=2
boy=2
girls=2
ss=1
```

How can this be improved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may do it like so,

```
Map<String, Long> wordCount = frequency.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
    .entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(Map.Entry.<String, Long>comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder())
        .thenComparing(Map.Entry.comparingByKey()))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, 
        (e1, e2) -> e2, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Output: `{gg=3, aa=2, boy=2, girls=2, ss=1}`

Notice that the mergeFunction is NOT used here since there are no key conflicts.

Comment: Thank you, but how can you sort the values ​​in alphabetical order, where the frequency is the same?

Answer (score 1):

Remove `.limit(limit)`, since it causes the `Stream` pipeline to process only the first `limit` elements (based on your output, `limit` was `6`).

```
return 
   frequency.stream()
            .map(String::toLowerCase)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),Collectors.counting()))
            .entrySet().stream()
            .map(entry -> new SimpleEntry<>(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Output:

```
[aa=2, ss=1, gg=3, girls=2, boy=2]
```

Comment: Hello @Eran
How to make it 
[gg=3, aa=2, boy=2, girls=2, ss=1]
So, how to make it sorted by value and if value equals - sort it sort by key e.g. boy=2, girls=2?